# Chat search RSS feeds aren't limited to the user or room when the chat search was limited to the user or room, causing more RSS results than necessary

Tags: bug, chat, search, feed

When I was trying to figure out how many times someone said `lol` on chat I saw that the RSS feed provides more than just his LOLts.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to [Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access), it's a pretty awesome and fun chat room.
2. Type `lol` in the top right chat box, because you want to enjoy all the fun there.
3. Filter by the user that has the most LOLts, because he knows how to be funny.
4. Now check out the link to the RSS feed in the right bottom, and there goes the fun away... :(

Expected result, supposing we have an awesome user in an awesome room:

```
https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/lol?user=1337&room=1337
```

Current result, which didn't satisfy me on 15 June 2012:

```
https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/search/lol
```

Comment: You must currently be in Iceland.